# Entity Framework Include() returns null navigational property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am having issue with the Include function. I have a Team class that has an Owner property of type Owner. I have a helper function that wraps my EF calls like below;

```
public Task<List<T>> GetManyAsync(
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null,
    Expression<Func<T, object>> includeProperties = null)
{
    IQueryable<T> query = _dbSet;

    if (filter != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(filter);
    }

    if (InstanceHelper.IsSomething(includeProperties))
    {
        query.Include(includeProperties);
    }

    return query.ToListAsync();
}
```

And I use it like this

```
var teams = await DataAccess.Team.GetManyAsync(e => e.Owner.Id == userId, e => e.Owner);
```

But it returns the list of Teams with a NULL Owner property. Any idea what I am missing here?

Comment: Is there `virtual` keyword specified before owners property declaration?

Comment: First you'll have to check whether it really is `null` in the database. Also, why not pass the expression? Why are you calling `GetPropertyName()` first and what does it return?

Comment: @Navoneel, The `virtual` keyword is to allow lazy-load. Once you're eager-loading the property, `virtual` is no longer required (although you'll lose change-tracking as well).

Comment: @haim770 you are right. just wanted to make sure op had it if

Comment: @haim770 GetPropertyName gets the property name that was specified in the includeProperty argument. I was just testing it. I used to pass string into the include but it gets messy with all the hardcoding of "column/property" names. I removed it from the pasted code above. Yes, I can see a value on the database. Owner_Id has some integer in it.

Comment: @Navoneel I don't have virtual in front of the property declaration.

Comment: Did you check the generated sql ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use from this

```
public Task<List<T>> GetManyAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties = null)
{
  foreach (var prop in includeProperties)
  query = query.Include(prop);
  ...
}
```

And you can have multiple includes

```
GetManyAsync(filter ,p => p.prop1 ,p.prop2,...)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: Well apparently - when I use include it doesnt apply it to the instance itself, it returns an IQueryable that I have to use instead and reassign it like you did. The foreach loop doesnt work though. But thanks!

Comment: @M.Azad How do you iterate on an object of type Expression<Func<T, object>>? I'm curious now...

Comment: @PlatypusMaximus I Update my answer